# Runnable Jar file doesn't work but the source code works fine. Maven Project JavaFX

Tags: java, maven, user-interface, javafx, nullpointerexception

I am currently learning JavaFX and trying to build small GUI. I think I am doing pretty good job. The only issue is when I run the program from Eclipse, it runs smooth but when I export it as Runnable Jar File and try to run it outside, it doesn't work.

It's a maven project and below is the main method of my program:

```
public class Main extends Application {

private Stage stage;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/main.fxml"));
    this.stage = primaryStage;
    primaryStage.setTitle("SLATE");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 700));
    primaryStage.show();
}

public Stage getStage() {
    return stage;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

I tried to debug it by running the JAR from terminal, below is the error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  .....
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
```

I feel that it has to do with the resource path I guess but I couldn't fix it any way. Weird thing is it works from Eclipse but JAR file doesn't with the same code.

Really appreciated your help. Note: [Project View](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5SeAyRbFySrbkFYUHhuNHJTYnM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are you exporting the `FXML` file with the `Jar` file ?

Comment: What is the `view` folder? Is it exported to the `Jar` File? If not, I think you need to add it to the run config or move the `main.fxml` outside the `view` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The path to your view seems to be wrong (as it uses the package-name of the current class), try this instead:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
Parent rootNode = (Parent) loader.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("view/main.fxml"));
```